# Infinite loop when trying to read and create a file

Tags: java, printwriter

This Java code compiles. But when I ran this program, it lasted a really long time and didn't get any results, and finally said runofoutspace, I guess it fell into an infinite loop, but I cannot figure out why.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Exercise3{
public static void main (String[] args){
File infile = new File(args[0]);
File outfile = new File("Ex3.txt");
try {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(infile);
  ArrayList<String> readFile = new ArrayList<String>();
  String findWord = args[1];
  String replaceWord = args[2];

  while(scan.hasNextLine())
  {
    readFile.add(scan.nextLine());
  }
  //System.out.println(readFile);
  for (int i=0; i<readFile.size();i++)
  {
    String n = readFile.get(i);
    n = n.replaceAll(findWord,replaceWord);
    readFile.add(i,n);
  }

  PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(outfile);
  for (int i=0; i<readFile.size();i++)
  {
    output.println(readFile.get(i));
  }
  output.close();
  scan.close();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e){
  System.err.println("file not found.");
}


  }
}
```

Comment: how does your program knows that it need to stop looking for input ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with :

```
  for (int i=0; i<readFile.size();i++)
  {
    String n = readFile.get(i);
    n = n.replaceAll(findWord,replaceWord);
    readFile.add(i,n);
  }
```

You are actually incrementing the size of the ArrayList, inside the for-loop.
***readFile.add(i,n);*** . Size of readFile gets incremented on each iteration of loop, so the loop condition would never evaluate to false.

When you add a new element at index i, the former element at the index will be shifted right. It won't be replaced.

Comment: He actually needs to call `.set` instead of `.add`

Answer (score 0):

That task can be done a bit more simple with the newer Files/Path API.
The oversight ofcourse was the usage of `add` - indeed adding.

```
Path infile = Paths.get(args[0]);
Path outfile = Paths.get("Ex3.txt");
String findWord = args[1]; // Maybe Pattern.quote(args[1])
String replaceWord = args[2];

Charsetch charset = Charset.defaultCharset(); // StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(inFile, charset);
for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i) {
    lines.set(i, lines.get(i).replaceAll(findWord, replaceWord));
}
Files.write(outFile, lines, charset);
```